# Magento 2 installation freeze at 0%

Tags: magento2, installation, apache, xampp

I am using windows 10 and xampp . Installation keep stuck at 0%. Some of the tables are created in database (30 or something). these are the errors that shown in the apache 2 error log

```
[Sun Feb 16 13:00:00.864775 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9652:tid 260] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Sun Feb 16 13:00:04.191132 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11932:tid 648] AH00428: Parent: child process 9652 exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting.
[Sun Feb 16 13:00:04.634088 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11932:tid 648] AH00455: Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Feb 16 13:00:04.634088 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11932:tid 648] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  9 2017 11:48:22
[Sun Feb 16 13:00:04.634088 2020] [core:notice] [pid 11932:tid 648] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Sun Feb 16 13:00:04.639089 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11932:tid 648] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1404
[Su
```

Comment: Magento is not supported on windows and although many have installed, this never fully worked on windows for me.  I would advise a VM or better yet use a native supported OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to install magento2 with Command 
its work fast

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://localhost/mag234/" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="mag234" --db-user="root" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="admin@admin.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --language="en_US" --currency="INR" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin"
```

change this command with your directory and DB

Comment: worked like a charm . Thanks brother

Answer (score 0):

Search msconfig in start menu or type in run, and under Services tab, make sure all services related to xampp are turned on.